# input file stream to command

Tags: command-line, files, arguments, input

How is it possible to send a file stream to this command instead of a file?

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --title "$SUBJECT" -q $SOURCEFILE $OUTPUTFILE
```

The file stream is from a string in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using `/dev/stdin` and PHP's [proc_open()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). Start the process with a command such as

```
wkhtmltopdf --title "$SUBJECT" -q /dev/stdin $OUTPUTFILE
```

and pipe the HTML you've got in your variable into the running process.

Comment: The input is not from another command but its a string from PHP

Comment: How do you retrieve it?

Comment: The string is from a `imap_*` function

Comment: So you're actually writing code in PHP, and you want to run `wkhtmltopdf` using input that you have in a variable in your program? Why not just write your string to a temporary file and run `wkhtmltopdf` using that?

Comment: I already do that.. but its faster without the temp file :)

Comment: Is the string you're manipulating the URL of the document you want to convert, or the HTML content?

Comment: its HTML content.. from an email

Answer (score 0):

to make a program that opens a file by name read from the pipeline give it the special device name `/dev/stdin` ... for example:

```
/usr/local/bin/program-to-output-the-html | /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --title "$SUBJECT" -q /dev/stdin $OUTPUTFILE
```

or do this before the command you showed:

```
SOURCEFILE=/dev/stdin
```

then the program will `open("/dev/stdin",...)` unless it has logic intended to defeat this.

Comment: often programs have logic to test if the given name is "-" and if so to use STDIN for input or STDOUT for output.

Comment: the file stream is from a string in PHP not another command line

Answer (score 0):

guessing from comment, you seems to be able to do it with a temporary file, why not make a named pipe ?

```
 mknod magritte p
```

inside you php code, just write to magritte.

wkhtmltopdf should be run with

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --title "$SUBJECT" -q magritte $OUTPUTFILE
```

you might specify the location more accurately.

Still guessing, wkhtmltopdf is run from within php ?

if yes, you need to run as a background process, see [php exec function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

call to exec is to be made before writing to pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The right thing so use is [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).

```
wkhtmltopdf --title "$SUBJECT" -q <(command_with_output_stream) $OUTPUTFILE
```